# Breakpoints not being hit in RubyMine in user code-- but will in ruby source

Tags: ruby, selenium, cucumber, rubymine

A colleague is using RubyMine (version 6) to run selenium and cucumber tests and up until yesterday afternoon was debugging happily along.

Now however, RubyMine isn't stopping on his breakpoints in our code.  They will stop however, in source ruby code such as kernel.rb.

This started suddenly, and the user in question swears he hadn't updated any gems or programs in the interim.  Where can we start to look when diagnosing?